# app crashes with error message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, datasource

In my UIViewController, I have added a subview which contains a uitableview.

```
MSEmployeeServiceController *empServices = [[MSEmployeeServiceController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MSEmployeeServiceController" bundle:nil];
[self.totScroll addSubview:empServices.view];
```

`MSEmployeeServiceController` class contains a `UITableView`. when i tried to add the view app crashes with the following error:

```
-[MSEmployeeServiceController numberOfSectionsInTableView:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x8684030
```

I have already set the the datasource and delegate connections in view.
Please help me.

Comment: When are you releasing the empServices object ?

Comment: post more code to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using **ARC**, make object of `MSEmployeeServiceController` a property like this in your **header file**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)  MSEmployeeServiceController *empServices;
```

Then in your **implementation** file,

```
_empServices = [[MSEmployeeServiceController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MSEmployeeServiceController" bundle:nil];

[self.totScroll addSubview:empServices.view];
```

Comment: Pleasure !! happy coding..:)